# URLrewrite on IIS7 for wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress blog installed in folder example.com/blog and now I want to use wordpress as CMS so I need to move wordpress to the root, the pages need to be in the root like example.com/page1 but I want that my blog posts will stay on example.com/blog/ with the defaults permalinks, example.com/blog/?p=123

How I do it via the web.config file on windows server?

Comment: I only need to use url rewrite functions of wordpress  , anyone know how I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding it, your best bet would to probably just keep two separate installations of wordpress.

Comment: I prefer to stay with one installation of wordpress if you have any suggestion for this